# grunt serve:dist fails on win10 with the message "Warning: EPERM: operation not permitted"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, windows, gruntjs, yeoman

I am trying to build an angularjs 1.x yeoman based application on node v6.3.1.

I can run `"grunt serve"` without any issues.

However, when I run it to create the distribution build using the command: `"grunt serve:dist"`, i get the following error and the command fails: **"Warning: EPERM: operation not permitted"**.

I am running grunt serve:dist for the very time on this project and infact for the very first time on this machine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I retried the build process a few times and on the third or fourth attempt, it worked and it has been working ever since. Weird!

Upon googling further I found [**this**](https://github.com/Medium/phantomjs/issues/19) URL which says that there could be many issues causing this same error message including AntiVirus software.

I did not disable my AntiVirus software. However, in my case, it's possible that the Antivirus software could successfully scan the new files after the third or fourth build attempts. Atleast that's what I think made the error go away and not come back.

So, if you encounter this issue, then try some of the solutions/workarounds listed in this URL.